# "Thanks for VERB + ing" vs. "Thanks to VERB": which is correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, word-usage, prepositions

Should I use *Thanks for being here* or *Thanks to be here*?
I have read that the first one is correct. 
However, I am not sure about these usages. Please tell me which one is correct and why it is correct.

Comment: What are the options?

Comment: Please describe it with the reasons

Comment: Which one do you think is correct? First, second, or both?  What explanation was given in the source where you read it?

Comment: You have to clear my concept.

Comment: I am not sure. 1st one seems to me correct.

Comment: Related, and possibly (but I'm not sure) a duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80896/thanks-to-command

Comment: Also, I'd say that none of the existing answers at the link I posted do a great job of explaining the difference between "thanks to" and "thanks for" (the closest is David McGowan's, but it doesn't go into much depth).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

'Thanks for being here' is correct. 'Being' is a verb in this case.
'Thanks to' would be followed by a noun e.g. 'Thanks to God' or 'Thanks to modern technology'

Comment: 'Thanks for being here' is you thanking someone else. 'Thanks to (someone) being here' indicates something (usually good) happened because someone was present here.